# How to heat up already baked french bread in oven to get a crispy crust

Tags: baking, bread, crust

Where I live I do not have access to great quality bakery breads. Is there a way to heat up an already baked french sandwich baguette in oven to get a crispy outer texture? Water mist on top before baking, egg wash etc?

Comment: Not an answer, but basic grocery store type bakery sections will often have "Italian" breads that are more or less identical to their "French" breads apart from having crispier crusts.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/43091/67

Answer (score 3):

In my experience you have 3 choices. Lightly spray with water, oil of your liking (olive, canola, grapeseed, or sunflower not vegetable, and lastly, my favorite, brush on lightly sweet unsalted butter.  Preheat your over to 350 degrees F (give or take 25 degrees) and do not keep in oven more than 5-7 minutes depending on how round your bread loaf is.  Another idea is to slice the bread, spread lightly with unsalted sweet butter and bake for 1-5 minutes in preheated oven 350 degrees F and keep a very close eye on anything you do with all these suggestions because you don't want to end up with croutons. Good Luck and realize I myself would bake my own suggestions starting with less time, let's say 1 minute first, check then add a minute, etc.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO If the bread was never frozen, the moisture from the crumb has infiltrated the crust and left the crumb drier. So the best bet is to put it in a moist oven for 5 minutes. Just use a spray bottle to squirter the sides and back of a 350 degree oven as you put the loaf in. If it is already cut (partial loaf) I cover the end with foil.

If you froze the bread, I have good luck microwaving 20 or more seconds depending on the size then finish in a hot oven to crisp it up.

As my dad said..."I don't love bread, I revere it". I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

To get a crispy crust and freshen lean dough breads like Baguettes or rolls:

Do not brush the surface with oil. Oil will stop a crispy crust forming. Period.

Mist the bread all over with water, or brush with an egg wash. Place in an oven at 200 - 220 degrees C (fan) for 10 minutes. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree with Kevin the Baker that if you want a crispy crust, and warmed center, the best approach would be to mist the bread with water, which I know sounds counter intuitive, but trust me, it makes for a nice crispy crust. Then go with a low oven setting, 220 degrees F fan (fan = convection) or 200 degrees F without the convection fan. After about ten minutes test for crispness by simply giving the loaf a little squeeze, or push on the middle of the loaf with a wooden spoon. Once you hear that nice crispy crackle, you're done. Don't go any longer than that in the oven, otherwise you'll dry out your bread.

Comment: Welcome! I am slightly confused: isn’t the rule of thumb to slightly _lower_ the temperature when using the fan setting ? Or is this a special case?

Comment: Kevin the Baker said 200-220 degrees C. Wouldn’t that be 400-425 (approximately) degrees F?